# Como verificar valores iguais de um Foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bem tenho dois `forEach`. O primeiro pega o valor de um `sessionStorage`, ou seja, o ID do bairro cadastrado pelo usuário. Já o segundo retorna todos os bairros cadastrados e seus respectivos IDS.

Eu queria fazer com que o id do bairro do `SessionStorage` seja igual ao ID do bairro cadastrado no segundo `forEach`. Mas se eu colocar o bairro cadastrado comparando no segundo `forEach` ele vai retornar 5 vezes o valor dos bairros cadastrados. Como que eu resolvo isso?

```
var getEnderecoLogado = sessionStorage.getItem("dadosendereco");
$.ajax({
    url: urlBase + "areaatendimento",
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (retorno)
    {
        parseResult = JSON.parse(getEnderecoLogado);

        parseResult.forEach(function (item)
        {
          bairrocadastrado = item.bairroendereco;
        });

        retorno.data.forEach(function (item)
        {
          id_atendimento = item.area_atendimento_id;
          id_bairro = item.bairro.bairro_id;
          nomecidade = item.bairro.municipio.nome;
          nomebairro = item.bairro.nome;
          nomeestado = item.bairro.municipio.estado.nome;
          valorfrete = item.valor_frete;
          valorfrete = valorfrete.replace('.', ',');

          if (id_bairro == bairrocadastrado)
          {
            $('.entregatotal').html("R$ " + valorfrete);
            $('.bt-finalizar-01 .finalizar-compra-carrinho').css('display', 'block');
          }
          else
          {
            $('.entregatotal').html('R$ 0,00');
            resultBairro = "<div class='mensagembairro'><strong>Atenção:</strong> O seu bairro não é atendido por este estabelecimento</div>";
            $('.finalizar-compra-carrinho').css('display', 'none');
            $('.delivery').css('display', 'none');
            $('.bt-finalizar-01').html(resultBairro);
          }

        });

    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
    console.log('Erro');
    }
});
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, quero que o ID do Bairro do Session Storage seja igual ao que volta no ajax para ver se pode calcular o frete ou não

Comment: Poderia mostrar o conteúdo da variável `getEnderecoLogado` ? E se possível também, o conteúdo do `retorno` do ajax.

Comment: Session Storage: [{"idcliente":"ecca2c6b-cd15-443b-b4db-5a15d39196c5","cependereco":"89400000","logradouroendereco":"rua teste","numeroendereco":"90","complementoendereco":"ewew","referencia":"wewew","estadoendereco":"Santa Catarina","cidadeendereco":"Porto União","bairroendereco":10813}] Vou por na resposta a imagem do retorno

Comment: Porque o `parseResult.forEach(function (item) { bairrocadastrado = item.bairroendereco; }` Esse `foreach` vai ficar apenas com o `ultimo item.bairroendereco`. Não consegui perceber qual era a intenção deste `for`

Comment: Sim mas ele não tem que pegar os valores do array do SessionStorage? Ele não tem que pegar o valor ultimo o do bairro, ou seja o ID do bairro?

Comment: voce nao precisa desse foreach, voce pode pegar diretamente 'parseResult = JSON.parse(getEnderecoLogado);' provavelmente vai ser alguma coisa como parseResult.data.bairroendereco

Comment: Mas isso pega sempre o ultimo. E se o objetivo for pegar sempre o ultimo (que eu duvido) então é mais fácil fazer `bairrocadastrado = parseResult[parseResult.length-1].bairroendereco` o que evitava percorrer a lista toda

Comment: da pra resumir tudo isso em `.last()` @Isac

Answer (score 1):

Com ES6 podes utilizar o "includes" conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
arr.includes(1) //resultado true
arr.includes(4) //resultado false
```

Se não for o caso de uso do ES6, podes ver no site da Mozilla o polyfill do "includes".

[Mozilla Polyfill includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains)

Comment: Isso nao seria uma boa solucao, primeiro pq é prototipo e segundo pq 
 nao tem  suporte para todos os navegores.

Comment: Sim e eu sei disso, por isso mandei junto um link com polyfills para este recurso, e se utilizar isso em um projeto com npm fica ainda mais fácil. :)